# Select records that match some of the input criteria

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am trying to implement a webservice that will take as input some ingredients, it will look up some recipies in a database and will return those ones that require all or some of the ingredients provided as input.

I can easily figure out the many to many relationship between the recipies and ingrdients so I am planning to have a table for recipies, one for ingredients and a link table in the middle. However, if I do this I am not sure how I can query the tables in an efficient way to get the information required.

To give an explicit example consider the following:

Input: Pasta, Chicken, Pesto, Tomatoes
Output should be:

- Pasta with Chicken in Tomato sauce (requiring Pasta, Chicken and tomatoes)
- Pasta with Pesto in the oven (requiring Pasta and Pesto)
- etc.

But output should not include Chicken with potatoes in tomato sause (since we do not have potatoes in the input ingredients).

I will be implementing this in Java and MySQL (although the Java part is probably not important for this question).

Can somebidy help me in approaching this. I am really after how to implement the Query but if you can think of other ways to approach it then these are welcome too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put your list of ingredients that are "desired" into a temporary table.  Let's call this "desired".

The following query will find recipes that have only ingredients in the desired table:

```
select r.recipe.name, group_concat(i.ingredientname separator ', ') as ingredients,
       count(*) as numingredients
from RecipeIngredient ri join
     Recipe r
     on ri.recipeid = r.recipeid join
     Ingredient i
     on ri.ingredientid = i.ingredientid left outer join
     Desired d
     on i.ingredientname = d.ingredientname
group by r.recipe.name
having max(case when d.ingredientname is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 -- all ingredients in list
```

Comment: This looks very good. It will take me some time to digest but I think that it should work. I will try it out and will let you know.

Comment: Looking again at the query and without having tried it yet, I think that there is one problem: I believe that it will not return the recipies that have only some of the ingredients. My requirement is to return the recipies that all their ingredients are in my list (and not vice versa). Have I read it incorrectly?

Comment: @Lefteris . . . This should return all recipes all of whose ingredients are in your list, although not all ingredients might be used.  The key is the left join and having clause.  If it finds an ingredient not in the list, then d.ingredientname will be null, and the record will fail the having clause.